# UITableView custom view for section header (memory leaks). What is correct method to make section's header custom view?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, memory-leaks, uitableviewrowaction

I am working on an app which has same UI as in "Instagram". I have a feed wall in which user scroll and see new picture added by friends, similar to instagram . Each  UITableViewcell has one picture and its own section Header view. I have achieved this by making sections for each cell. But I am worried about the memoryleak

Here is my code

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 45))
        headerView.tag = 101

        let imageView :UIImageView   = UIImageView(frame: UtilityManager.setFrameWithOutHeight(CGRectMake(22, 5 , 30, 30)))
        imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        imageView.tag = 101
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor
        headerView.addSubview(imageView)

        var label = UILabel(frame: UtilityManager.setFrameWithOutHeight(CGRectMake(50, 5, 320 - 60 , 35)))
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        label.textColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 0.28, blue: 0.27, alpha: 1)
        label.text = "I'am a test label"
        label.font = UIFont(name: Constants.FONT_MEDIUM, size: 12)
        headerView.addSubview(imageView)
        headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    return headerView
}
```

Btw I am using Swift. Its so cool isn't it ;) . Let me explain more about this delegate function to make custom section's header. Each time when any of my cell or section comes on screen this delegate method is getting called even if I scroll back to the section whose's headerView has already been allocated. So headerView is being created multiple times for one section while scrolling. But I know It is wrong method there must be something to checking weather headerView has already been created or not. Is there any way to put a check in code if my views does exist in memory then no need to allocate memory again. 
Somebody please help :). I will appreciate even a small help.

Answer (score 5):

You generally want the same memory management and cell reuse pattern that Cocoa provides for table cells, so use `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`.
 In `viewDidLoad:` call `tableView.registerClass(UITableViewHeaderFooterView.classForCoder(), forHeaderFooterReuseIdentifier:"Header")`

Now you can dequeue these views on demand in your delegate methods, such as:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let headerView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    if let reusedView = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier("Header") as? UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
        // Remove the existing contents of the reused view
        map(reusedView.contentView.subviews) { 
            $0.removeFromSuperview() 
        }
        headerView = reusedView
    } else {
        headerView = UITableViewHeaderFooterView(reuseIdentifier:"Header")
    }

    let imageView = ... // Set up image view
    let label = ... // Set up label  

    headerView.contentView.addSubview(imageView)
    headerView.contentView.addSubview(label)

    return headerView
}
```

Cocoa disposes and reuses these header views as needed now.

This implementation is much more straight-forward if you subclass `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` and add your image and label properties (then you won't have to remove and then add subviews to a dequeued view, only replace them by name).  Also if you design a nib for your class or use a table view cell for your view through a storyboard, dequeuing will never return nil.

Since you mention you may have "infinite cells", maybe you are worried about holding too much of your data source in memory (maybe you have a huge number of large images for those image views).  In that case you'll need to set up some sort of cache.  Take a look at `NSCache` if you get to that point.  No need to implement your own cache.

At OP's request, I'll elaborate a bit on how this dequeue system works in Cocoa.  You probably have similar code in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method.  Imagine that your user is scrolling downward through your table view.  You have cells and headers going offscreen at the top of your table view, and new ones appearing at the bottom of the table view.  All of these cells have a similar format.  Now assume that Cocoa doesn't do anything special (no queue of cells).  Disappearing cells would get deallocated, and appearing cells would get created from scratch.  Instead, Cocoa tries to be efficient and keeps a queue of these cells/headers on hand.  It won't create any more than it needs to display on the screen at any one time.  When one of the cells goes offscreen, it puts it into a queue and that cell then becomes available to be dequeued (taken out of the queue) later by you.  When you dequeue a cell or header (you ask for it according to its reuse identifier string), it will give you the exact view that went offscreen (or one of them).  Once you get it, you configure it as you need.  Yes, in the code above you have to still create the `UIImageView` and `UILabel` (I'll explain how you can and should do even better below), but the main `UIView` and any kind of decorating views that don't need to be changed will still be there (no computational cost for reusing them).  So basically Cocoa helps you recycle these views, making things very efficient and safe.

You'll notice that when the code above tries to dequeue a cell, it's in an `if let` statement that tests whether it is nil.  This is important because if you are just loading your table view, it doesn't have any cells/views in the queue to give you, so if it's nil, then you instantiate a new view from scratch.  When you instantiate it, you give it a reuse identifier string.  If this view goes offscreen later, Cocoa knows to put it in its special queue to give back to you later.  As I noted above, though, if your view is loading from a nib or storyboard, dequeuing will always return non-nil.  One final detail about loading from a nib, you'll want to register the reuse identifier using `registerNib:forHeaderFooterReuseIdentifer:` method of `UITableView`.

Now you can see how Cocoa handles these cells/view very efficiently by not requiring you to instantiate new views whenever your user scrolls through the table view, you might be a little disappointed in my code above that still has you removing all of the old subviews and instantiating new `UIImageView`s and `UILabel`s, and indeed you should be disappointed.  The recommended way to get around this is by subclassing `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`, or you can really subclass any `UIView`.  Make a property for imageView and label.  Now instead of destroying the subviews with the old content and then creating these views again, just replace their contents with the new appropriate content (`imageView.image = newUIImage` and `label.text = newString`).  Believe it or not, this will save a lot of computation.  `UIView`s are somewhat costly to create.  A sloppy (though potentially more flexible) alternative to subclassing would be to put tags on these views that you want to insert using the `tag` property and then get a reference to these views later using `headerView.viewWithTag(anInt)`.

And I hate to have all of this talk of headers to be for nothing, but I'll make one final observation.  I noticed you say that every cell has its own header.  If this is true, you'd probably be better off with just making one large table cell (put your header content above your normal table view cell content).  You could skip using headers all together.  I don't know everything that is going on in your app, though, so I'll just let you make the judgment on that one.

Good luck to you @Ankush!  Knowing the ropes around `UITableView` is a great iOS skill that I'm sure you'll find useful in the future!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Its seems to be working :) . Can you elaborate your answer more please ? I am newbie in case of UItableView. I dont know how exactly this dequeue thing work. Does this above code you provided mean each time when section will be on screen then code will remove all the subviews and recreate them ?

Comment: Happy to elaborate, @Ankush.  It got a bit long, so I have it in my edited answer above.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. Just one more question. As i need to have infinite cells probably, then, wouldn't there be any memory issue ? As you explained that cocoa puts each cell, in a queue, which is offscreen (that means each cell will be present in memory ). So shall I have to make my logic to make this infinite tableView ?

Comment: `UITableView` was definitely built with an infinite number of cells in mind (Okay maybe just up to `Int.max` :).  Don't worry about memory leaks.  Cocoa doesn't save every possible cell.  When a cell goes offscreen, it will be put in a queue. When you need a new cell that is just appearing, it will reuse this cell. When that cell goes offscreen again, it can be enqueued and recycled again. That's the beauty of the table view. It may look like to the user that there are thousands of uniquely created cells, but in reality your app only made maybe 20 cells and just recycled and reconfigured them.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to implement caching of the header views on your own. The framework won't do it for you. You could just create an array instance variable to hold all of the allocated views. In the delegate method you then create and cache or simply return the header view.

```
var headerViews = [UIView]()

func createHeaderView() -> UIView {
    let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 45))

    ...

    return headerView
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    while section >= headerViews.count {
        headerViews.append(createHeaderView())
    }

    var headerView = headerViews[section]

    // Set up the header view (image, text, ...)

    return headerView
}
```

Note that this is probably not the most efficient way of doing it since you'll keep all of the header views around once they were created. When you know the maximum number of header views displayed at the same time, you could incorporate some kind of cache eviction strategy and reuse existing header views.

---

## Update

Below is a variation of the above code that reuses a maximum of 20 header views. This will work as long as headers that are 20 sections apart from each other do not display on screen at the same time.

```
var headerViews = [UIView]()

func createHeaderView() -> UIView {
    let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 45))

    ...

    return headerView
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let maxNumHeaderViews = 20
    let index = section % maxNumHeaderViews

    while index >= headerViews.count {
        headerViews.append(createHeaderView())
    }

    var headerView = headerViews[index]

    // Set up the header view (image, text, ...)

    return headerView
}
```

The key point, however, might be that there is no memory leak in the code you posted in your question. Cocoa will keep the view you return retained for as long as it is displayed and release it when it is not needed anymore.

Comment: But what if I need infinite cells? As feeds in feedwall are not limited.

Comment: @Ankush I added a small variation that reuses at most 20 different header views to give you an idea.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it :)